# jQuery Continously receive Updates from webservice

Tags: jquery, html

I have a webservice which continuously sends some updated data from a thirdparty server.

I have made a jQuery Webservice call to call that webservice, should I be frequently polling from my jQuery to receive the updates?

Can i implement this without using Websockets or SSE?

Answer (score 0):

If you need real-time updates then polling is the way to go. If you are using a javascript framework like Angular or Backbone, check out this plugin which helps in caching and improving performance.
try http://www.breezejs.com/

Web sockets is alternatively a very good way to go about this.   However, consider that you will have to do changes on front end and server end.